# Different results between Azure portal and shell

Tags: azure-cli

If I run the CLI command

```
az storage account list
```

from https://shell.azure.com I get the result [] i.e. no storage accounts found

However if I switch to https://portal.azure.com I can see 22 storage accounts listed.

Can anyone explain why I am getting different results for the same authenticated account.

Comment: It seems so strange. Do you check if the user account and subscription are the same? Usually, you could see one storage account that persists the cloud shell at least.

Comment: My problem was that I had multiple subscriptions for the account and I needed to set the subscription related to the storage accounts first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your storage accounts are ARM(Azure Resource Manager) model, the two results should be the same.

1.Make sure you have checked them in the same `subscription`, in the cloud shell, you can use `az account show` to get it.

2.The `az storage account list` is just for the `ARM`, if your storage account is `classic`, it will not return it.